# How to show the equivalence of the following statements? $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$

Tags: functions

$X, Y$ are quantities and $f : X → Y$ a function. Show
the equivalence of the following statements:

(i) $f$ is injective

(ii) $f^{-1}\!\bigl(f(A) \bigr)=A  \quad \text{for all}~ A \subset X$

Comment: Following the community guidelines, please tell what you have tried and where you got stuck (even if you are stuck just not understanding some part of the problem itself).

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know how to start. That's the best I can come up with $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in X|f(x)\in f(A)\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show the equivalence of two statements.
For that we show $I)\Rightarrow II)$ and $II)\Rightarrow I)$

For $I)\Rightarrow II)$.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be injective and $A\subseteq X$.

We have to show, that $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$. So equality of two sets. For that we have to show:

a) $f^{-1}(f(A))\subseteq A$

b) $f^{-1}(f(A))\supseteq A$

a):

So let $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in X| f(x)\in f(A)\}$. So so it exists an $a\in A$, with $f(x)=f(a)$. 
Since $f$ is injective, it is $x=a$. So $x\in A$.

b):

Now let $x\in A$. We have to show, that $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Since $x\in A$, it is $f(x)\in f(A)$, and $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in X| f(x)\in f(A)\}$ so $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$ by definition.

Note, that we did not need to use, that $f$ is injective here!

Now we have to proof $II)\Rightarrow I)$.

Let $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ for EVERY $A\subseteq X$.

We want to show, that $f: X\to Y$ is injective, so suppose for $x,x'\in X$ it is $f(x)=f(x')$. We have to show, that $f(x)=f(x')$

Suppose $x\neq x'$.
Now observe $X\setminus\{x\}= A$ and $X\setminus\{x'\}=B$.

Obviously it is $A\neq B$. (Indeed: Since $x\in B$ with $x\notin A$ and $x'\in A$ with $x'\notin B$.)

Now $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in X| f(x)\in f(A)\}\stackrel{f(x)=f(x')}{=}\{x\in X| f(x)\in f(B)\}=B$

So $A=B$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Analysis Feel free to ask. It mostly boils down to the definition.

Comment: a)  $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in X :f(x)\in f(A)\}$ Since $f(x)\in f(A)$ one can deduce that there has to be at least one $a\in A$ with $f(x)=f(a)$, right? Since $f(x)$ is a subset of $f(A)$ there has to be at least one element.

Comment: Your deduction is not clear. The existence of such an $a$ follows immediatly from the definition. We already know, that $f(x)$ is an element of $f(A)$. So there is an element $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=f(x)$.

Comment: That's what I mean, sorry English is not my native language, especially when it comes to mathematics.

Comment: Ok. And now since $f(a)=f(x)$ and $f$ is injective it follows $x=a$ so $x\in A$, as we were supposed to show.

Comment: b) is pretty easy to understand. But $II) \Longrightarrow I)$ is hard to understand for me. Suddenly, there is another quantitiy $B$. What's the quintessence of that proof? We're going to assume that $X\backslash \{x\}=A$ and that $X\backslash \{x'\}=B$ which leads to $A\neq B$ I do not understand the last line: $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in X| f(x)\in f(A)\}\stackrel{f(x)=f(x')}{=}\{x\in X| f(x)\in f(B)\}=B$ How are you using $\stackrel{f(x)=f(x')}{=}$ given the fact that that's the equation one has to prove...?

Comment: The idea of defining A and B that way, is to use, that the property of II) holds for EVERY subset of $X$. The fact, that $f(x)=f(x')$ (which is our assumption) is here used to effect, because $A$ does not contain $x$. But it is $x'\in A$. And so it is still $f(x)\in f(A)$, because it is $x'\in A$ and so it is $f(x')\in f(A)$ for sure. But $f(x)$ and $f(x')$ are the same element. They are equal. So you do not have to proof, that $f(x)=f(x')$. It is our assumption, as I said. We have to proof, that $x=x'$. For that we involve a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, but I guess I have solved it via "direct proof" myself. Thanks a million!

Comment: Thats even better. You are welcome.

Comment: Is it valid though? Let $x,x'\in X$ . Suppose $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$. Therefore $x \in f^{-1}(f(x'))$. The fact that  $f^{-1}(f(x'))=x' $and $x \in f^{-1}(f(x'))$ leads to $x\in x'$, thus $x=x'$

Comment: No, unfortunatly this is not a valid proof. First of all $f^{-1}(f(x'))=x'$ has not to hold. There can be other elements. You confuse here the 'preimage' with the 'inverse function'. Also you write $x\in x'$. Which is wrong, because $x$ and $x'$ are not sets, but elements of $A$

Comment: That's unfortunate...

Comment: No big deal. Just keep on trying. You are just starting with math and everyone made those mistakes, or was confused at the beginning. I am still confused all the time. :) You have to understand how to do math. Some proofs are kinda 'forced'. This is an example for it and you have to wrap your head around the definitions and what there is to show. If this task is to difficult, go in your lecture notes and study them. You might notice, that the proofs in your notes are most of the time easy to understand. That is the best way to learn math at the beginning. And dont give up.

Comment: Thanks for the motivating words. Actually, I am 16 years old and have been given the chance to further refine my math skills at a university. I have never been confronted with such problems before, hence I am having problems solving them...

Comment: As I said, that is completly normal. But you are in a dangerous time now, because you might know from school, that you understand everything at the first time. Universitiy math is different. It is complex and hard work. Also you are in a position now, where you have to learn for yourself, and no teacher who explains it to you. So I recomment you to study the lecture notes, and go through the given proof step by step. And always ask yourself WHY. Why does this equality hold? Why can I conclude this from that etc.

Comment: Yeah. University Math is really different. But I had no problems with the previous problems whatsoever, like proving that $A∩(B∪C)=(A∩B)∪(A∩C)$ or $x\cdot 0=0$ via (i guess they're called "field axioms" in English). But the problems with functions really stress me out

Comment: Cornman, I guess I have solved the problem with the previous "direct proof": Let $x,x' \in X$ under the assumption that $f(x)=f(x')$. Furthermore  $x\in f^{-1}(f(\{x'\}))$. Since $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ for every $B⊂X$ is $ f^{-1}(f(\{x'\}))=\{x'\}$. And since $x\in f^{-1}(f(\{x'\}))$ it is $x\in \{x'\}$ and thus $x=x'$

Comment: @Analysis Yes, this looks good. You might want to write down in your proof why exactly is $x\in f^{-1}(f(\{x'\}))$. Also the next line is a little bit odd, because you phrase in two ways, the assumption, that $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$, for every $A\subseteq X$. Also you talk about a subset $B\subseteq X$, but never use $B$ again. You might leave that away, and reduce the proof to only things, that are necessary for it to understand, and add those things, so noone who reads it, is in doubt that you are right.

Comment: Ok, having recapitulated your answer I did not understand why in a) we know that $f^{-1}(f(A))⊂A$. I think you showed that $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$ and $x\in A$. But how do we know that $f^{-1}(f(A))⊂A$ and not $A⊂f^{-1}(f(A))$? Couldn't it also be the other way around?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I suggest exerimenting with simple examples:

1. Let $X = \{x_{1}, x_{2}\}$, $Y = \{ y_1, y_2, y_3 \}$, and $A = \{x_2\}$.

1a)  Let
$$
f(x_{1}) = y_1, \quad f(x_{2}) = y_3.
$$
Draw a picture of $f$:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
X & & Y\\ 
x_{1} & \rightarrow & y_{1}\\
x_{2} &  & y_{2}\\
& \searrow & \\
& & y_3\\
\end{array}
$$

Is $f$ injective?  What is $f(A)$?  What is $f^{-1}(f(A))$?

1b)  Let
$$
f(x_{1}) = y_1, \quad f(x_{2}) = y_1.
$$
Draw a picture of $f$:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
X & & Y\\ 
x_{1} & \rightarrow & y_{1}\\
& \nearrow \\
x_{2} &  & y_{2}\\
& & y_3\\
\end{array}
$$

Is $f$ injective?  What is $f(A)$?  What is $f^{-1}(f(A))$?

Comment: Thanks, but how does this prove the equation?

Comment: @Analysis It is not supposed to proof anything. avs wants that you work through an example, so you get a better grip and understanding of the used terms/definitions so you can use that in the proof.

Comment: Okay, but as far as I am concerned none of the cases in the avs' answer are injective functions.

Comment: @Analysis, what is the definition of "injective"?

Comment: @Analysis, as Cornman pointed out, this problem is about knowing thoroughly the definitions involved.  I suspect, you have some gaps there (e.g., my first $f$ actually *is* injective), which is why you are struggling also to wrap your head around Cornman's complete proof.